# How to minimize applications to system tray instead of taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, notification-area

I am trying to find a way to minimize an app into the system tray instead of it taking up space on the taskbar.

Back in the day, there was [PowerMenu](http://www.abstractpath.com/powermenu/) app which added `Minimize to Tray` to menu items right next to Move/Size/Minimize/Maximize.  Unfortunately that doesn't work with Windows 10 anymore.

I've also tried RBTray which appears to only work with explorer windows.

Is there a way to minimize applications to the system tray?

Comment: https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/minimize-app-to-system-tray-windows-10/ Seems that the app "Minimize to Tray" will do what you want

Answer (score 4):

The app [RBtray](https://github.com/benbuck/rbtray) works well for explorer windows. It does not work with the Whatsapp Desktop version. After installing, it allows you to minimize almost any window to the taskbar instead of the system tray.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm really late n all but if you still have need for specifically Whatsapp Desktop here are a couple option to minimize it to system tray.

https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/whatsapptray.html

https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/whatstraybutton.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).